# Shannon's Entropy Algorithm Returning negative values

Tags: c++, c, entropy

note: project is in C, not C++

```
float entr = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < map->entry_count; ++i)
{
    float x = (float)map->entry[i].occ / map->entry_count;
    if(x > 0)
    {
        entr -= x * log(x) / log(2);
    }
}
return entr;
```

when my map has 3 occurences of value 15, the entropy returned is -4.214.. something

when my map has 3 occurences of value 15 and one occurence of value 25, the entropy returned is 0.000

something is clearly wrong here. i don't really understand the maths behind it, so i got the algorithm off the internet, but i'd really like to get it to work.

BTW, the map is written by me. i cannot provide the code (it's for production), but:

- occ = the number of occurences for a single value
- entry_count = the number of values in the map. it does not increase when occurences increase, it increases when a new value is added

so basically it works just like a C++ map, to my knowledge

Comment: OT: `log` and `log2`  returns a `double`, if you want to use a `float` switch  to `logf` and `log2f`

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did not look at the prototype. Replaced float with double now

Comment: `entr` starts at 0, and you only ever subtract positive values from it, so it will always be negative or 0.

Comment: @dbush: The formula for entropy is essentially correct. The `x` in the summation should be in [0, 1], so they will have zero or negative logarithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `x` in `x * log(x)` should be the probability of the item for `x`. That could be calculated as the number of times the item occurs divided by the total number of occurrences of items. But it is calculated as `map->entry[i].occ / map->entry_count;`, which appears to be the number of times the item occurs divided by the number of items. This makes it greater than it should be.

For example, if the 3 events/items/things A, B, and C occur 10, 13, and 17 times, respectively, then the `x` values should be 10/40, 13/40, and 17/40, but the source code in the question appears as if it would use 10/3, 13/3, and 17/3.

Comment: I am now keeping track of the total number of values entered and the code became `map->entry[i].occ / map->total_entries`, which in the case of providing the values `15 15 15 25` would equate to `3/4` and `1/4`, but the value is now always zero (i may have misinterpreted what you said, though)

Comment: Actually, i think I know what the issue is. I am casting to double too late, I will check if casting sooner works